# my function is returning nothing

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS TotalProductionCost;
CREATE FUNCTION TotalProductionCost(Abuilt int(10),Ucost Decimal(5,2) )
RETURNS Decimal(5,2)
BEGIN
DECLARE TotalCost Decimal(5,2);
SET TotalCost = Abuilt * Ucost; 
RETURN TotalCost;
END //
DELIMITER ;

SELECT TotalProductionCost(10,1000) AS TotalCost;
```

I have created above function when Execute it in mysql workbench it worked fine query executed,but when I called function,it didnt return anything.. query executed suceefully.

Comment: This should return something.  One note, is that you are trying to return `10000` in a `DECIMAL(5, 2)`, which will result in truncation and data loss, q.v. [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/85025).  You might want  to increase the precision of your return type if you plan to use such numbers as input.

Comment: Yes ..I increased precision and its worked..Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The sizing of your decimal is exploding based on your input and output of (5,2).

The following works:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS TotalProductionCost;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION TotalProductionCost(Abuilt int,Ucost DECIMAL(12,2) )
RETURNS Decimal(12,2)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE TotalCost Decimal(12,2);
    SET TotalCost = Abuilt * Ucost; 
    RETURN (TotalCost);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

test:

```
SELECT TotalProductionCost(10,1000.12) AS TotalCost;
```

So, yes, I confirmed yours choked. And you need to be careful with your sizing for the in and return.

Comment: Also always do the `DROP` before the delimiter set. So you had lines 1 and 2 reversed. But yes @JuanCarlosOropeza is was weird

Comment: Thanks everyone.. Yes.. It didn't generate any error.,